# ZF2 - Custom Validator via factory

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, factory, instantiation, custom-validators

I cant load my **CustomValidator** via factory:

```
namespace My\Validator;
class CustomValidator extends AbstractValidator
{
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, AuthenticationService $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->em = $em;

    parent::__construct();
}
```

**Module (My) Config**:

```
namespace My;
...
'service_manager' => array(
  'abstract_factories' => array(
    'Application\Factory\FormAbstractFactory'
  ),
),
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'My\Controller\CustomController' => 'My\Factory\Controller\CustomControllerFactory',
    ),
),
'validators' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'My\Validator\CustomValidator' => 'My\Factory\Validator\CustomValidatorFactory'
    ),
),
```

**CustomForm**:

```
namespace My\Form;
class CustomForm extends SearchForm implements InputFilterProviderInterface {
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager, Translator $translator) {
        parent::__construct ($objectManager, $translator,  "customForm" );
        // Here are some elements added...
        $this->add(array("name" => "search", /* some more properties */));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'search' => array(
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'My\Validator\CustomValidator'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

**CustomValidatorFactory**:

```
namespace My\Factory\Validator;
class CustomValidatorFactory implements FactoryInterface {
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $sl = $serviceLocator->get("service_manager");
    $entityManager = $sl->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    $auth = $sl->get('zfcuser_auth_service');

    return new CustomValidator($entityManager, $auth);
}
```

I get a PHP error saying that __construct's first parameter ($em) must be an instance of EntityManager, none given...
My Factory is not instantiated... I think my CustomValidator is still created by some other factory (or ValidatorPluginManager?)...
How do I have to change my code to get my CustomValidatorFactory working?

**EDIT** - complete Exception by rendering view with form which has my custom validator attached:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to My\Validator\CustomValidator::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in /xxxxxx/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 252 and defined in /xxxxxx/module/My/src/My/Validator/CustomValidator.php on line 32
( ! ) TypeError: Argument 1 passed to My\Validator\CustomValidator::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in /xxxxxx/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 252 in /xxxxxx/module/My/src/My/Validator/CustomValidator.php on line 32
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  369208  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.1165  11279664    Zend\Mvc\Application->run( )    .../index.php:28
3   0.2780  17578688    Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest( )    .../Application.php:356
4   0.2780  17578688    Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent( ) .../Application.php:384
5   0.2780  17578688    Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners( ) .../EventManager.php:251
6   0.2781  17580376    call_user_func:{/xxxxxx/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:490} ( )    .../EventManager.php:490
7   0.2781  17580376    Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render( )  .../EventManager.php:490
8   0.2781  17580376    Zend\View\View->render( )   .../DefaultRenderingStrategy.php:103
9   0.2786  17591848    Zend\View\View->renderChildren( )   .../View.php:200
10  0.2787  17592840    Zend\View\View->render( )   .../View.php:236
11  0.2789  17593272    Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render( )   .../View.php:207
12  0.2792  17633952    include( '/xxxxxx/module/My/view/my/view/index.phtml' ) .../PhpRenderer.php:502
13  0.2810  17743208    Zend\Form\Form->prepare( )  .../index.phtml:13
14  0.2810  17743208    Zend\Form\Form->getInputFilter( )   .../Form.php:203
15  0.2819  17885496    Zend\Form\Form->attachInputFilterDefaults( )    .../Form.php:696
16  0.2836  18054248    Zend\InputFilter\Factory->createInput( )    .../Form.php:801
17  0.2837  18054888    Zend\InputFilter\Factory->populateValidators( ) .../Factory.php:265
18  0.2837  18054944    Zend\Validator\ValidatorChain->attachByName( )  .../Factory.php:408
19  0.2837  18054944    Zend\Validator\ValidatorChain->plugin( )    .../ValidatorChain.php:194
20  0.2837  18057312    Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get( )   .../ValidatorChain.php:97
21  0.2839  18068224    Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get( )  .../AbstractPluginManager.php:161
22  0.2839  18068920    Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create( )   .../ServiceManager.php:532
23  0.2839  18068920    Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate( ) .../ServiceManager.php:599
24  0.2839  18068920    Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->createFromInvokable( )   .../ServiceManager.php:640
25  0.2839  18069160    My\Validator\CustomValidator->__construct( )    .../AbstractPluginManager.php:252
```

**EDIT2** - **FormAbstractFactory**:

```
class FormAbstractFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface {

    public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        return (fnmatch('*Form', $requestedName)) ? true : false;
    }

    public function createServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        if (class_exists($requestedName)) {
            $entityManager = $serviceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
            $translator    = $serviceLocator->get('translator');

            return new $requestedName($entityManager, $translator);
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

**CustomControllerFactory:**

```
namespace My\Factory\Controller;
use My\Controller\CustomController;
class CustomControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $entityManager      = $realServiceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        // Created through FormAbstractFactory
        $customForm          = $realServiceLocator->get('My\Form\CustomForm');
        $orderByService     = $realServiceLocator->get('Application\Service\OrderByServiceAbstract');

        return new CustomController($entityManager, $customForm, $orderByService);
    }
}
```

**CustomController**

```
namespace My\Controller;

class CustomController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $entityManager, CustomForm $customForm, OrderByService $orderByService)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->form = $customForm;
        $this->orderByService = $orderByService;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // some code...

        $vm = new ViewModel (array(
            "form" => $this->form
        ));

        $vm->setTemplate("my/custom/index");

        return $vm;
    }
}
```

**my/custom/index - View:**

```
<?php
namespace My;
$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare(); ?>
<!-- HTML Stuff... ->
<?php echo $this->form($form, null); ?>
<!-- HTML Stuff... ->
```

Well I am using a custom form-renderer too - https://github.com/neilime/zf2-twb-bundle.

I filed an issue at zf2's git: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/7688

Comment: The factory's first line `$serviceLocator->get("service_manager")` should be `$serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()`. Also, might make more sense to rename the `$serviceLocator` variable to `$validatorPluginManager` to save confusion.

Comment: Thanks... I edited my code and retried - but still no luck. The displayed exception still hints, that AbstractPluginManager tries to create the Validator from Invokable: Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->createFromInvokable( ). I think something is wrong in how I configured my validator... Any clue?

Comment: What you have should work, although It seems odd to me that the input filters throwing this error in the view rather than the controller - makes me think that the view is the first place the form is created? Also, are you creating the form via `$formElementManager->get('name_of_form')`?

Comment: Please tell us how do you instantiate the form. Just for the record, the factory is named `AlertValidatorFactory`, but in the config you refer to it as `CustomValidatorFactory`. If you use PHP 5.5 use FQCNs instead of strings, modern editors will typehint if the class is missing or not, eg: `My\Validator\CustomValidator::class => My\Factory\Validator\CustomValidatorFactory::class`

Comment: @mike sorry was a typo (wanted to make it more general by not using my domain-specific keywords (like alert), corrected my question). I tested your approach in my config and IDE (Jetbrains PHPStorm) does not complain about missing classes:
namespace My;
...
'validators' => array(
        'factories' => array(
             Validator\CustomValidator::class => Factory\Validator\CustomValidatorFactory::class
        ),
    ),
...

Comment: The [ZF2 bug "Custom validators registered through ValidatorProviderInterface not found"](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4219) could be the problem.

Comment: @AlexP thanks for the link. I will post there too and state my problem referencing this thread. 
Note: I also updated my question-post with lots of additional detail (edit2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the form's via the `ServiceManager`.

```
$customForm = $realServiceLocator->get('My\Form\CustomForm');
```

Which means you have the abstract factory registered with the *service manager* rather than the form element manager. By doing this the form will be created [without form factory's input filter being correctly prepared](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/FormElementManager.php#L247).

Move this config to the 'form_elements' key.

```
'form_elements' => [
     'abstract_factories' => [
          'My\Form\FormAbstractFactory',
     ],
 ]
```

In `CustomControllerFactory` you would need to update to.

```
$formElementManager = $realServiceLocator->get('FormElementManager');
$customForm = $formElementManager->get('My\Form\CustomForm');
```

And finally the `FormAbstractFactory::createServiceWithName()` method will now need `$serviceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()` at the top.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't see it! Validator now instantiated through factory.

Comment: oh one thing to add: the array-key is "abstract_factories" not "abstract_factory"...

Comment: You can propose an edit by yourself on anyone's posts.